# c# embed resources problem on windows xp (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, resources, nullpointerexception

I'm using an embed resources in my c# application

```
string sPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sPath, Properties.Resources.test)
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(sPath,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

It worked fine until today,It throw me some bad exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at ......

It is only on 2 windows xp proffesional edition installations, both root and user accounts (user account is very limited there, because of admin policy).

Till today it worked on several xp and vista installation, without any problems.

What could be a cause of this problem?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Localization? What are the user / system locales on those machines and in your app?

Comment: by the Localization what you mean?

Comment: Add a try and catch in that block of code and print out the error message, I'm assuming the null reference is from workbook?

Comment: yes, it is from function that deals with woorkbooks.

i will paste error message tomorrow, because it is now after office hours and i don't have access to those computers.

Comment: ok, error from try-catch block is System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory....

I figured out, that this could be a problem with microsoft office version, because on those machines is office 2000, i have done installation on other computer in this office with installed office 2003 and now it seems to be everything ok.

But still, i don't know the solution in case when office 2000 is installed, any ideas? upgrading office is not avaible now :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this would be a reference issue due to version problem as you stated. Since you added in a reference to the Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library (2003 excel) then I don't think you can create an Microsoft Excel 9.0 (Excel 2000) app. I've never tried dealing with different versions but maybe you can add both reference in and open them in a try and catch when one fails.

pseudo code

```
try{
workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(sPath,missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
}
catch ( NullReferenceException e )
{
      // This means the user is in Excel 9.0 (Excel 2000)
      // Open workbook as Excel 2000
}
```

Hope this helps